# Broken Access Control with JWT in Python

Tags: python, jwt, pymysql

I'm currently working on a project to create a secure login with JWT and python. It's a simple bank account app that shows the username, date of birth and account balance. In my code, I'm still able to access other accounts by changing the URL account numbers assigned to other users such as **[www.domain.com/account/#](http://www.domain.com/account/#)**.

If `foo` is account 16 and is logged in, I'm able to change the numbers to 17 allowing me to access `bar`'s account presenting their info which is a big no no. I want to only be able to only see `foo`'s own account information. I'm trying to check the JWT to make sure that `foo`'s is the user and it is `foo`'s account information before sending the data to the user.

The JWT that is passing to the function includes a `username`, and `logged_in` field (or claim) of the authenticated user. I'm trying to compare with the account that is being looked up in the database via the number in the URL. I'm also trying to make sure that if the username in the JWT does not match the username returned from the DB then to raise a "You do not have access" exception.

I've been beating my head against the wall to figure this out.

**Payload**

```
jwt_token = {
      "username": "foo",
      "logged_in": true
    }
```

**Code**

```
import jwt
import pymysql


class LoggedOutException(Exception):
    '''Raising a LoggedOutException will redirect the user to the login screen
    in the app.
    '''
    pass

def account_lookup(account_id, jwt_token):
    try:
        token = jwt.decode(jwt_token, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
    except Exception as e:
        raise LoggedOutException('User is not logged in')

    if "logged_in" in token.keys() and token["logged_in"] == True:
        conn = pymysql.connect(
            host='mysql',
            port=3306,
            user='root',
            passwd='letmein',
            db='BankApp'
        )
        cursor = conn.cursor()

        statement = "SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE id = " + account_id + ";"
        cursor.execute(statement)
        username_results = cursor.fetchone()

        if username_results:
            username = username_results[0]

            statement = "SELECT balance, dob FROM tbl_account WHERE user_id = " + account_id + ";"
            cursor.execute(statement)
            account_results = cursor.fetchone()

            conn.commit()
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()

            return {
                'balance': account_results[0],
                'dob': account_results[1],
                'username': username
            }
        else:
            raise Exception('Account not found')
    else:
        raise LoggedOutException('User is not logged in')
```

Answer (score 2):

if username_results and username_results[0] == token['username']:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm also trying to make sure that if the username in the JWT does not
> match the username returned from the DB then to raise a "You do not
> have access" exception.

Where? There is no such logic in your code. You are using the JWT only to check whether the user is logged in or not based on the `logged_in` value which doesn't help much because only logged in users should hold a valid JWT token, therefore the presence of such token itself represents the logged-in status of a user.

The logic should be something like when a user logs in, you generate a JWT token for that user and when that user logs out, you invalidate that token (of course, you might want to consider implementing token age and refreshing as well later on).

You have 2 SQL queries in your code

```
statement = "SELECT username FROM tbl_user WHERE id = " + account_id + ";"
statement = "SELECT balance, dob FROM tbl_account WHERE user_id = " + account_id + ";"
```

but they depend only on the value of `account_id` which is not part of the JWT (and why are you using `account_id` name for the variable if it is clearly a `user_id`? It is just confusing).

The easy solution would be to place `account_id` (or to name it more properly `user_id`) into JWT instead of `username` which should not be there anyway (in my opinion), and use that value to fetch data from DB.